# How to override Plotly.js methods (downloadImage) using vue-plotly module

Tags: vue.js, plotly.js

By default, [vue-plotly](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/vue-plotly) component provides a download button with arbitrary values for the output image, resulting in low quality PNG.

Is it possible to override the [downloadImage](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlydownloadimage) method ?
The github repository readme specifies that the module provides all plotly.js events and methods, but I didn't find a way to do so.

Can someone provide a minimal example or give me some pointers to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

I tried the following with no success:

```js
<template>
    <v-container>
        <Plotly 
          v-if='!loading'
          :data.sync="data"
          :layout="layout"
        ></Plotly>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { Plotly } from 'vue-plotly';

export default {
    components: {
        Plotly
    },
    },
    data () {
      return {
        data: [],
        layout: {
          autosize: true,
          title: "MyTitle",
          showlegend: true,
        },
        loading: false,
      };
    },
    mounted () {
      this.loading = true;
      this.loadData().then(data => {
        this.data = data;
      }).catch( (error) => console.log("Error loading data: ", error) );
      this.loading = false;
    },
    methods: {
      downloadImage () {
        return Plotly.downloadImage(
          {
            format: 'png', width: 800, height: 600
          }
        )
      },
      loadData () {
        // Loading my data
      },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a vue expert, but plotly image export options can be set using `config.toImageButtonOptions`:

```
config = {
  'toImageButtonOptions': {
    'format': 'svg', # one of png, svg, jpeg, webp
    'filename': 'custom_image',
    'height': 500,
    'width': 700,
    'scale': 1 # Multiply title/legend/axis/canvas sizes by this factor
  }
}
```

According to the vue-plotly docs you should be able to pass an additional prop to the Plotly component which will then be passed to the plotly chart as a config object, see https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/vue-plotly#props (Others)
Something like

```
<Plotly
  :data="data"
  :layout="layout"
  :config="config"
></Plotly>
```

```
data () {
      return {
        data: [],
        layout: {
          autosize: true,
          title: "MyTitle",
          showlegend: true,
        },
        config: {
          toImageButtonOptions: {
            format: 'svg',
            filename: 'custom_image',
            ...
          }
        }
      };
    }
```

Comment: Tried your solution and the download button still forces the output file to be png. Also, compared to the Plotly documentation, the hint associated to the button changes from "Download plot as a png" to "Download plot" if the `toImageButtonOptions` is passed, which doesn't occur in my case. And I don't get any js error in console.

Comment: Looking at the vue-plotly sources, I tried a slightly different approach and it worked. So instead of passing a config array to the Plotly component, I passed a `to-image-button-options` prop (following the usage example with `display-mode-bar`) with the `toImageButtonOptions`array. And it works. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction ! I can't edit your post to include this change, can you do it ? Otherwise I'll post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

According to @mit and @Beinje s' comments, I have tried this and this worked for me.

```
<Plotly :data="..." :layout="..." :toImageButtonOptions="{format: 'svg', scale: 1}"/>
```

See reasons [here](https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/vue-plotly#api). It means any other props except for data, layout and id should be directly passed into the element.

> Props:
>
> - data Array (optional): Data to be displayed
> - layout Object (optional): Graphic layout
> - id String (optional): Id of the root HTML element of the component.
> - Others:
>   Plotly component implements the transparent wrapper pattern:
>   All other props will be passed as plotly graphic option.